# How to use div.load properly when calling for a partial view in another controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So i have this code that calls a popup dialog that contains a partial view. The problem is that whenever i call the dialog div.load appends the entire string block to the address of the home controller.

```js
function OpenSendMessagePopUp() {
    var div = $("#DivAppendToPartialView");
    div.load("@Url.Content(~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml)", function () {
        div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 420,
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            title: "Send Message",
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
     
    });
}

function SaveMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml")',
        data: {
            smsContentId: smsContentId,
            comments: comments
        },
    });
```

The MobileNumberUpload is the home controller for the project while Resend is the controller for the Partial View. Note that I cannot combine the two controllers as per the constraints of the project.

[Error Message for when i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Ctg.png)

[This is the dialog that pops up when i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPR1I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below changes :

```
function OpenSendMessagePopUp() {
    var div = $("#DivAppendToPartialView");
    div.load('@Url.Content("~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml")', function () {
        div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 420,
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            title: "Send Message",
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
}

function SaveMessage() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml")',
    data: {
        "smsContentId": smsContentId,
        "comments": comments
    },
});
}
```

Also make sure **smsContentId** and **comments** should be declared in JS.

Comment: The uncaught reference error has been solved, but the initial error still persists. The address still remains as localhost/MobileManagementWebSites/MobileNumberUpload/@Url.Content(%22~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml%22)?_=1493975137234

Comment: Try using `@Url.Content("~/Resend/_SendMessage.cshtml")` without using quotes around it.

Comment: Tried it, javascript does not accept @ as a valid character so it sent back an Uncaught Reference Error with the function OpenSendMessagePopUp.

Comment: @JRAgliam, it worked for me when I have included same code in my project. `@UrlContent` will not work if your page is normal html page, it should be a **.cshtml** or **.vbhtml**.

Comment: i see now thank you, i placed the function in a js file to separate it from the view itself. it works now, thank you :)